# Inverse Function Theorem for Functions That Aren't Continuously Differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, inverse-function, nonlinear-analysis, inverse-function-theorem

I am trying to show that given the vectors $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$, the system of equations given by
$$\mathbf{a}=\mathbf{x}_2 - \mathbf{x}_1$$
$$\mathbf{b}=\frac{\mathbf{x}_1}{\lVert \mathbf{x}_1 \rVert^3}-\frac{\mathbf{x}_2}{\lVert\mathbf{x}_2\rVert^3}$$
can be inverted to solve for $\mathbf{x}_1$ and $\mathbf{x}_2$ in a neighborhood around some point.

Assuming that $\mathbf{x}_1 \neq \mathbf{x}_2$, $\lVert \mathbf{x}_1 \rVert \neq \lVert \mathbf{x}_2 \rVert$, and $(\lVert \mathbf{x}_1 \rVert,\lVert \mathbf{x}_2 \rVert)$ are non-zero for the point of interest.

The problem with the Inverse Function Theorem is that it requires the functions to be continuously differentiable. Clearly, the second function is not continuously differentiable about $\mathbf{0}$.

If I were given the function
$$\mathbf{c}=\frac{\mathbf{x}}{\lVert \mathbf{x} \rVert^3}$$
and asked to find $\mathbf{x}$ given $\mathbf{c}$ I know this can be inverted because it is easy to see that $\lVert \mathbf{x} \rVert = \lVert \mathbf{c} \rVert^{-1/2}$, but the Inverse Function Theorem would not be able to prove that this is invertible. Are there any other methods of determining whether or not a nonlinear function or system of nonlinear functions is invertible about a point?

Comment: The problem statement is confusing, since you are apparently using the same name for a variable and for a particular value. Moreover, the function *is* $C^1$ everywhere on its domain. So your objection seems irrelevant.

Comment: Its continuous on its domain but doesnt the Inverse Function Theorem require it to be continuous everywhere? Or am I missing something. Because it isnt continuous at zero.

Comment: Study the theorem.

Comment: I did study the theorem, I still don't know the answer. The theorem requires continuous differentiability, which my function has about its domain but the theorem doesn't specify whether or not continuous differentiability is required on the domain or everywhere. Could you just tell me? That's why I'm here asking the question.

Comment: On the domain. Otherwise what you’re saying makes no sense.